# Serilog, insert log into specific database in a multi-tenant application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, connection-string, serilog

I have a WebAPI write in .net core 5, that connects to the correct database based on a key passed through JWT.

es.

```
--> Key = A dbconnection string "Data Source=1.1.1.1;Database=A;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
--> Key = B dbconnection string "Data Source=1.1.1.1;Database=B;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
--> Key = B dbconnection string "Data Source=1.1.1.1;Database=C;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

and so on...

The connections are stored in another database which is used for general configurations, including connection strings for various clients.

Now we want to add serilog that inserts the logs into the various databases. But I can't figure out how to tell Serilog to have dynamic connection strings, at this moment it is only possible to insert one connection string.

Is it possible to retrieve the connection strings for Serilog on the fly before entering the log?

Comment: You described how you think the solution would look, not the problem. The real problem is you have a multi-tenant application and want to store the logs to the correct tenant's database. And the connection strings come from another database

Comment: yes, i can't get the correct connection string... this is my problem... there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a custom implementation of Serilog's `ILogEventSink`. It defines a single method `void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)` which you would implement yourself to emit the log to the desired destination.

Once that is done, and you are setting up your `LoggerConfiguration`, you would call `myLoggerConfiguration.Sink(mySink, minLogLevel);` to tell Serilog to log to that "sink".

Comment: Mmm nice I try this Monday... Thx