# In my .NET 6 project, I need to process files for different companies and maintain separate logs. How can I achieve this?

Tags: .net, .net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog in my project for logging.

**Flow Explaination:**
I will receive a request on api. The request will contain provider value. Using the provider value we will call the respective provider dll. And call the specific function in dll and return the response to the user.

**Problem:**
When i am using a provider A i want a log folder to be named `logs/A/log00102.txt` for provider B it should be `logs/B/log00102.txt`. These folders will be generated in my WebApi project which is making use of these dlls. 
What are possible solutions to achieve this functionality?.

Additionally, How can i have logs configured in my dlls. So the log statements in those dll will get dumped in the Api project when they are used.

[image: Architecture]

Comment: Serilog is a logging framework, not a file-processor... Please explain _what, exactly_ you are doing...

Comment: Be sure to look at Serilog.Sinks.Map. But in general I'd advise against having file per tenant like you're planning - better to make sure there's nothing sensitive in it and have one file thats easier to manage (or ideally a centralised log server)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to take advantage of the ILogEventEnricher interface:

```
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

public class CustomerIdEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private readonly string customerId;

    public CustomerIdEnricher(string customerId)
    {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(new LogEventProperty("CustomerId", new ScalarValue(customerId)));
    }
}
```

Wire it up like this:

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Logger(customerLogger => customerLogger
            .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Properties.ContainsKey("CustomerId"))
            .WriteTo.File((customerIdLogEvent) =>
            {
                var customerId = customerIdLogEvent.Properties["CustomerId"].ToString();
                return $@"logs\{customerId}.log";
            }, LogEventLevel.Information)
        )
        .CreateLogger();
```

Usage:

```
    var customerId = "12345";
    Log.ForContext<CustomerIdEnricher>().Information("Customer {CustomerId} logged in.", customerId);

    Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

This might be OK for a small website if you don't have many issues, though many websites these days use one of the logging companies like Grafana, Splunk, Sumo or etc for governance and compliance.

Comment: Thanks for you solution. I have made few changes in my question and tried to explain more clearly what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Its turning into a chameleon question, instead of customer now its provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question points to a similar direction of what you are trying to accomplish, maybe it will help: [Serilog, insert log into specific database in a multi-tenant application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344040/serilog-insert-log-into-specific-database-in-a-multi-tenant-application)

---

> Alternatively, if there's a better solution, I'd appreciate your guidance.

I'd say that is better to keep them all together, so you can perform cross-companies analysis if needed. For that, add a `Tenant` field to your logs. You can do it by following the explanations in the "ABP Framework + Serilog" section of [this article](https://blog.infernored.com/logging-current-user-and-tenant-in-asp-net-boilerplate/).
There are two main steps:

1. Add the relevant information (in your case the tenant) to the Serilog context in a middleware:

```
public class SessionLoggingMiddleware : IMiddleware, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly ICurrentTenant _currentTenant;

    public SessionLoggingMiddleware(ICurrentTenant currentTenant)
    {
        _currentTenant = currentTenant;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("TenantId", _currentTenant.Id))
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Configure Serilog to use that information from the context and add it to the   logs:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Async(c => c.File("Logs/logs.txt", outputTemplate:
        "{Level:u4} [{TenantId}] [{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"))
    .WriteTo.Async(c => c.Console())
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution. I have made few changes in my question and tried to explain more clearly what i am trying to achieve.